# Are there Lojasiewicz-Simon estimates with boundary?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

Let $M$ be an analytic manifold with boundary $\partial M$, equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$, which is also analytic up to and including the boundary.

> Are there Lojasiewicz–Simon estimates available for minimal surfaces $\Sigma$ in $M$ with $\partial \Sigma \subset \partial M$? If necessary, assume that $\partial \Sigma$ is analytic also.

I would also be interested in the special case where $M$ is the Euclidean ball $B^n \subset \mathbf{R}^n$.

My naive guess for a formulation in a manifold *without boundary*, still denoted $M$ would go as follows; this is essentially copied verbatim from Leon Simon. Let $\Sigma \subset M$ be an embedded, smooth minimal surface.

- Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the minimal surface operator over $\Sigma$, and $\mathcal{A}$ the area operator, so that if $u \in C^1(\Sigma)$ has small enough norm, then $\mathcal{A}(u) = \mathcal{H}^n(\operatorname{graph}_{\Sigma} u)$; in particular $\mathcal{A}(0) = \mathcal{H}^n(\Sigma)$.
- Let also $\mu \in (0,1)$ be an arbitrary Hölder exponent, and $\beta > 0$ be a constant small enough in terms of $\Sigma$ to guarantee the ellipticity of $\mathcal{M}$ over $\Sigma$. Finally, let $\mathcal{S} = \{ \zeta \in C^2(\Sigma) \mid \lvert \zeta \rvert_{C^2} < \beta, \mathcal{M}(\zeta) = 0 \}$.

There are constants $\theta \in (0,1/2)$, $\gamma \geq 2$, $\sigma > 0$ so that if $u \in C^{2,\mu}(\Sigma)$ has $\lvert u \rvert_{C^{2,\mu}} < \sigma$
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\lvert \mathcal{M}(u) \rvert_{L^2} \geq (\operatorname{inf}_{\zeta \in \mathcal{S}} \lvert u - \zeta \rvert_{L^2})^\gamma
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\lvert \mathcal{M}(u) \rvert_{L^2} \geq \lvert \mathcal{A}(u) - \mathcal{A}(0) \rvert^{1 - \theta}.
\end{equation}

Comment: It would help if you could specify exactly what estimate/result you are looking for.

Comment: @OtisChodosh I'm interested in either of them. The boundary would have to be fixed, so you'd be fixing $\Gamma \subset \partial M$ and looking at surfaces that all have $\partial \Sigma = \Gamma$. If you don't do that the estimates don't work because there's (many) examples of minimal $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2 \subset B$ that are arbitrarily close with different areas. Is that what you were alluding to?

Comment: Can you write the estimate that you call "LS estimate" in the case of minimal surfaces in $S^3$ without boundary? I can imagine several statements.

Comment: @OtisChodosh I wrote down an explicit version. I wasn't aware of the ambiguity, so I just copied the estimates from Leon Simon's original paper. What are the other statements you're referring to? (For the record, I originally wrote down a version with boundary, but I didn't feel that confident in it, so I replaced it with the above.)

Comment: I could also see a doubling construction that would give the boundary versions automatically, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I see what you are after. I don't think this is written down anywhere, but I would just go through Leon's "Singularities of energy minimizing maps" chap 3 and check. There will be some changes in e.g. (5)  on p 76, since you need to use boundary estimates. But I would think it goes through OK. Actually, I am not sure whether or not you need $\partial\Sigma$ analytic (but probably $\Sigma$ itself analytic is important).

Comment: @OtisChodosh Cool, I'll take a look - thanks for the suggestion! Could you clear up what the ambiguity was? I didn't know there were any other Lojasiewicz-Simon estimates.

Comment: No, actually I am not sure what I was thinking about yesterday... Sorry for any confusion